# Backreference before capture group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the text `Page x of x` so I can identify the last page in a document.

I've been playing around with capture groups, and found the regex `Page (\d*) of \1` almost works, except that it also matches things such as `Page 2 of 25`. Ideally, I'd like to use `Page \1 of (\d*)`, but I guess the regex engine doesn't support that.

I should also note that this is part of an OCR job, so I can't rely on string endings, since occasionally I pick up extra characters (`Page 2 of 25la`, for example)

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\d+` instead of `\d*`. Also check for the end of digit using lookaround as well.

```
Page (\d+) of \1(?=\D)
```

Comment: Since you don't know if there is or not a character after, it is better to use `(?!\d)` (that is equivalent to `(?=\D|$)`)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the tips. I am Learning everyday.

Comment: Unless there could be a page with `Page  of`, it doesn't matter whether you use `*` or `+`.

Comment: @SabujHassan: Like all of us! <°))))))>

Comment: This won't match if the target input is at the very end of the input

Answer (score 1):

Add a look ahead:

```
Page (\d*) of \1(?=\D|\Z)
```

The look ahead will match when the input following the back reference is a "non digit" character or end of input.

Comment: @Barmar good point. You've made me realise that the technically correct answer is actually more complicated than I first thought

Answer (score 1):

But instead of a extra character like `a` at the end you could get an extra digit. And then you could be at the last page of your doc but the regexpr does not match.

Maybe the best way to attack this problem is to start with the simple regexp

```
Page\s+(\d+)\s+of\s+(\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-fKheYrj0ycf-pS0)

and iterate over all occurances to somehow overcome this nasty extra character problem and get the max page number right. And after it is clear how many pages there are, then to check where group 1 equals group 2.

I included `\s+` in my regexp. This should also be necessary due to your data.

But in the end there is only a chance that it will work depending on the accuracy of the OCR processing.